# Where can I get a list of reserved keywords in C#?

Tags: c#, keyword

Where can I get a list of reserved keywords in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Microsoft's [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx):

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008/.NET Framework 3.5

- abstract
- as
- base
- bool
- break
- byte
- case
- catch
- char
- checked
- class
- const
- continue
- decimal
- default
- delegate
- do
- double
- event
- explicit
- extern
- false
- finally
- fixed
- float
- for
- foreach
- goto
- if
- implicit
- in
- int
- interface
- internal
- is
- lock
- new
- null
- object
- operator
- out
- override
- params
- private
- protected
- public
- readonly
- ref
- return
- sbyte
- sealed
- short
- sizeof
- stackalloc
- struct
- switch
- this
- throw
- true
- try
- typeof
- uint
- ulong
- unchecked
- unsafe
- ushort
- using
- virtual
- void
- volatile
- while

Comment: You forgot `__makeref`, `__reftype`, `__refvalue`, and `__arglist` :)

Comment: So add them then. You have edit privileges.

Comment: -1, a list like this should mention the version.

Comment: @Henk: So why didn't you add it then?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you need the keywords because you are automatically generating C# code to be compiled, you can use, for example, `@new` as a variable identifier even though `new` is a reserved word.

I'm having trouble finding the specific MSDN link explaining that, but csharp-online has [this page](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_What_does_at_sign_identifier_mean) on it.